# vue-test-utils. Mocked vuex is used in .vue file, but original vuex is used in .ts file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, testing, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I'm testing my vue project with vue-test-utils.

Because my project has used the vuex store, I mocked the vuex in test files.

The problem is it seems that .vue file calls mocked store and .ts file calls original store.

Here are my codes.

**transfers.test.js**

```
...
const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(ElementUI)
localVue.use(Vuex)
localVue.component('DefaultLayout', DefaultLayout)

const store = new Vuex.Store({ // Mocked store
  state: {
   transferDetailModal: false,
...
},
  mutations: {
    showTransferDetailModal (state, detailPayload) { // It makes 'transferDetailModal' true
      console.log('run2')
      state.clickedTransferDetailId = detailPayload.transferId
...

  const wrapper = mount(Transfers, { // Mount component using mock store
    localVue,
    store,
    mocks: {
...

  describe('TransferDetailModal', () => {
    test('open and close', async () => {
      expect(wrapper.find('.transfer_id_column button').exists()).toBe(true)
      wrapper.find('.transfer_id_column button').trigger('click') // It calls mutation.
      await nextTick()

      console.log(wrapper.vm.getTransferDetailModal)
      // It logs getter of 'transferDetailModal', and false.
    })
```

**TransferState.ts(module of vuex store)**

```
...

export const transfersStore: Module<TransfersState, RootState> = { // Original vuex store
  state: {
...
},
  mutations: {
    showTransferDetailModal (state, detailPayload: { transferId: string, remittanceList: Array<Remittance> }) {
      console.log('run1')
      state.clickedTransferDetailId = detailPayload.transferId
...
```

**Transfers.vue**

```
...
export default class Transfers extends Vue {
  @Getter getTextObjectStatus: any
  @Getter getTransferDetailModal: any // @Getter is the expression of vue-property-decorator
...
```

**TransfersPresentation.ts**

```
...
callback: () => {
          store.commit('showTransferDetailModal', { transferId: remittance.id, remittanceList: this.remittanceList }) // It makes transferDetailModal true
          console.log(store.getters.getTransferDetailModal) // It logs true
        }
...
```

The process is

1. Callback of TransferPresentation is called when wrapper.find('.transfer_id_column button') is clicked in a test.
2. Commit in a callback makes 'transferDetailModal' true. But 'run1' is logged, it means that the mutation of original vuex store is called not the one of mocked store.
3. console.log(store.getters.getTransferDetailModal) in a TransferPresentation also logs it as true. It means that getter of original store is get.
4. But, console.log(wrapper.vm.getTransferDetailModal) in a test file still logs it as false. It means that it still gets a getter of mocked Store. (When I test with changing mocked store's value to true, it logs true)

So how can I make the getter and commit in a TransferPresentation(the .ts file) also refer to mocked store, not original one?

Answer (score 0):

To be more precisely you are not mocking the store, you are using the real store but the one you created in a test file.
If you want to `mock` you should remove your `store` object and include all your `Vuex store` logic in `mock` property while calling `mount`, e.g:

```
const wrapper = mount(Transfers, { 
    mocks: {
      $store: {
        getters: {
          // your getters
        },
        actions: {
          // your actions
        },
      }
   }
);
```

If you want to keep testing the way you have already started the problem might be in fact that you didn't called `localVue.use(Vuex)` before mounting the component, at least you didn't show that line in provided code.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem by not mocking vuex store, but using the original store like below.

**index.ts**

```
Vue.use(Vuex)
...
const store: StoreOptions<RootState> = {
  state: {
    ...
  },
  mutations: {
    ...
  },
  actions: {},
  modules: {
    ...
  },
  getters: {}
}

export default new Vuex.Store<RootState>(store)
```

**transfers.test.js**

```
...
import indexStore from '../../store/index'
...
const localVue = createLocalVue()
...
localVue.use(Vuex)
...
const store = indexStore

describe('With params: all', () => {
  ...
  const wrapper = mount(Transfers, {
    localVue,
    store,
  ...
```